# The magic behind MATLAB's powerful matrix decomposition algorithms

Tags: matrices, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I have always wondered how MATLAB's built-in function for matrix decomposition are crafted and optimized. Examples of MATLAB's built-in function for matrix decompositions are $\mathsf{qr},\mathsf{svd},\mathsf{chol}$ I always wondered how do these functions have their algorithm written with optimized speed and stability performance. Moreover, does there exist algorithms that out performs these built-in functions?

Comment: GNU Octave, which is very similar to MATLAB in its functionality and (i assume) speed, has its entire source code available on github which you can explore: https://github.com/gnu-octave/octave

Comment: These routines are not written in matlab language, that would be very inefficient. They all use what is called LAPACK (Linear Algebra Pack), which is a compiled library of linear algebra routines. The exact details with respect to the algorithms can be found in LAPACK documentation http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/lapack_lug.html.